# Using WebGL or OpenGL ES 2, how do I render the contents of an RBO onscreen?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, webgl

Using WebGL (which is constrained to the OpenGL ES 2 API), I am successfully rendering to texture and then displaying that texture onscreen.  Because it is a texture, it is not being antialiased.  If I were rendering to an RBO and then displaying that onscreen, I would be able to take advantage of AA.

My render target setup looks like this:

1. Create FBO
2. Bind FBO
3. Create texture (to be rendered to)
4. Create and bind depth buffer as RBO
5. Attach texture and RBO to FBO

And my rendering update loop looks like this:

1. Render the scene to the FBO created in step #2 above
2. Render a screen aligned quad with the texture created in step #3 above

With desktop OpenGL, I would call `glBlitFramebuffer()` instead of drawing the screen aligned quad.

How do I render my scene with antialiasing?  Do I need to replace the texture with an RBO?  If so, what calls do I use to bind the RBO to draw a screen-aligned quad?

Comment: Why you can't use AA? On the first rendering just attach an anti-alias shader and you should be done... You could also super sample your scene rendering to a big texture and then sub sampling it

Comment: Normal AA is disabled on many machines due to driver issues. It's probably something that will work itself out over time but until then there's no way to force it on programmatically.

Comment: But he/she can use a programatic Anti alias... take a look for example to SMAA (http://www.iryoku.com/smaa/)... it would take a little effort, but the results are great

Comment: It is definitely possible to apply AA in post by implementing one of the available methods but that doesn't help me understand what the correct way is to do render the contents of an RBO onscreen with OpenGL ES 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot blit the contents of an RBO to screen in WebGL unless you perform a readback and re-upload to texture to blit, which is rather slow.

WebGL has no support for MSAA on FBOs in any form (neither as RBO nor as RTT).

You can implement your own antialiasing in a variety of ways.

- Render at 2:2 size and scale down (google maps with webgl does this)
- Render at 1:1 size, run a sobel or laplace edge detection on color and depth, and run a bilateral gaussian blur using edge strength as weight (I've used this technique in some of my demos, it works well, http://codeflow.org/entries/2011/apr/11/advanced-webgl-part-1/ )
- Use the morphological antialiasing recipe from GPU Pro 2 (I've yet to try that)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I have been keeping an eye on your work as I progress on mine.